# Could not load wrapper properties, properties file contains code from xml

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This has been happening to any New Project I create in Android studio, as soon as it loads it tells me

> Could not load wrapper properties from gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

But then inside the gradle wrapper it has this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http:/
```

Now i'm pretty sure this isn't what I should be having inside my gradle
properties file.

As in my working projects, this is what I normally have.

```
#Wed Jul 29 12:16:27 AWST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Seems a bit out of reach of my debugging techniques, any help would be great thanks before I do a complete fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, deleted the cache folder inside C:\Users[Username].AndroidStudio4.0\system
and it sorted it out :)